# Using two menus in Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I am trying to create a Wordpress theme with two menus.

In functions.php I have registered the menus:

```
register_nav_menu('main', 'Main navigation menu');

register_nav_menu('topmenu', 'Top navigation menu');
```

And in my theme header I have called them:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main' ) ); ?>

<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' =>  'topmenu' ) ); ?>
```

However, the 'main' menu shows up in both locations.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Read the Wordpress documentation on [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out now, I needed this in functions.php: 

function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'main' => __( 'Main Menu' ),
      'topmenu' => __( 'Top Menu' )
    )
  );
} 

And this in my header.php:

<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'main' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'topmenu' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 1):

You needs to login to WordPress dashboard. Click Menus from left side.

You can see Theme Location options there. Set the menu there.

[**Read this codex section**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel)